# How to add and call additional Get Method in ASP.net WebAPI Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My WebAPI project contains following Controller.

```
public class StateController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/State
        public IEnumerable<State> Get()
        {
            return new StateRepository().GetAll();
        }


       ////////////// How to call this method from client code ?  ////////////// 
        public IEnumerable<State> GetAllByCountryId(int id)
        {
            return new StateRepository().GetAllStatesByCountryId((short)id);
        }

        // GET: api/State/5
        public State Get(int id)
        {
            return new StateRepository().Get(id);
        }

        // POST: api/State
        public void Post([FromBody]State state)
        {
            new StateRepository().Create(state);

        }

        // PUT: api/State/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]State state)
        {
            new StateRepository().Update(state);
        }

        // DELETE: api/State/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            new StateRepository().Delete(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to call this method - `GetAllByCountryId(int id)` from `IEnumerable<State> Get()` method right ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed your route config as below ? Id is required in the same.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by adding following code to WebAPIConfig.cs

```
// Controller Only
// To handle routes like `/api/State`
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerOnly",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);

// Controller with ID
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerAndId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
);

// Controllers with Actions and Id
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerAndActionAndId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
);
```

Comment: Please edit your original question with additional edits rather than posting them as answers.